# Error integration PlusOneButton google api key

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-play-services, google-plus

**I have here a ListView -:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/colorGrey"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**And there is a custom item -:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_image_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />


    <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        plus:annotation="inline"
        plus:size="standard" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I deduce a list of suggestions. I wish that each proposal has its own button one but I did not then not up when I add a button without key all ok!

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms: play-services: 10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-auth: 10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-plus: 10.0.0'
}
```

**The preview gives item.xml this -:**

[image: please see this image]

I googled this problem and found a comment in which he wrote that this problem occurs if juzat library com.google.android.gms: play-services above 7 version, so I do not think that google threw in Prodakshen not working version and as it is already out of 10 th, I suspect they changed the api key or something like that, I integrated the button with the help of this documentation here from google: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend is an old documentation and have the new ?

Answer (score 0):

First, please ensure that you already [enabled the Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_2_enable_the_google_api).

Then, you may want to check if you already have done [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) with the latest version of `play-services` when updating the declared dependencies in  your project.

As mentioned in [Add Google Play Services to Your Project](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup),

> 2. add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of `play-services`.
>
> Be sure you update version number each time Google Play services is updated.

You might want to also check this [(Google plusone (+1) button in Android application integration guide](http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/09/google-plusone-1-button-in-android-application-integration-guide.html) for more information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you, I did it all, and all renew and even cache completely overthrown Fully rebuilt project, everything works except the button :(